# Merge styles using JSS in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I'm new to using JSS but since we're building our current project with Material UI, I figured I would try to follow their style API using JSS with the custom components I have to build occasionally for the app.

In this instance I can get the styles to work just fine, however, this particular component has a dynamic `backgroundUrl` that gets set from props passed in and I'm trying to figure how I'm supposed to somehow merge the class coming in with the new `backgroundUrl` style I need to dynamically set...

The styles

```
export default {
  root: {
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    padding: '25px 20px',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    backgroundPosition: '50% 0',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(40,70,94,.7)',
    backgroundBlendMode: 'multiply'
  }
};
```

The component

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './EventTop.styles';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

const EventTop = ({ event, classes }) => (
  <aside className={classes.root} style={{ backgroundUrl: `url(${event.event_logo})` }}>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="event-info">
        <span className="event-time">
          7:00 PM
        </span>
        <span className="event-date">
          27 Jun 2020
        </span>
        <span className="event-end-time">
          Ends at 10:00 PM
        </span>
        <span className="event-title">
          Bidr Gala
        </span>
        <span className="event-attire">
          Cocktail Attire
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(EventTop);
```

Currently, it's a style tag but that gets stripped out when I apply the class, how do I merge these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use inline styles, you don't need to merge classes. It should work already. Your problem is that backgroundUrl is not a valid css property, it is backgroundImage.